# TSQL statement being skipped over

Tags: t-sql

I am having a hard time figuring out why only the beginning part of my code is executing. I have inserted the statement '--Nothing after this point is executing' where the problem lies. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
IF @i_numrecs = 0
BEGIN 
    SET @nextid = dbo.Timesheetgetnextid(@EMP, @DATE)

    IF @mode = @c_current
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO timedetail (
            ppenddate,tsdate,empnum,task1,
            task2,task3,hours,minutes,
            doecode,duration,SOURCE,enteredby,
            enteredon,approved,completed,timein,
            timeout,id)
        VALUES(
            @DATE,@DATE,@EMP,' ',
            ' ',' ',0,0,
            ' ',0,'BROWSER',@UID,
            @actiondate,'N','Y',' ',
            ' ',@nextid)

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO adjst_timedetail (
            ppenddate,tsdate,empnum,task1,
            task2,task3,hours,minutes,
            doecode,duration,SOURCE,enteredby,
            enteredon,approved,completed,timein,
            timeout,id)
        VALUES (
            @DATE,@DATE,@EMP,' ',
            ' ',' ',0,0,
            ' ',0,'BROWSER',@UID,
            @actiondate,'N','Y',' ',
            ' ',@nextid)

    END

    --Nothing after this point is executing
    INSERT INTO timesheetchangelog (
        empnum,tsdate,tdid,changedate,
        changeby,SOURCE,changetype)
    VALUES(
        @emp,@date,@nextid,@actiondate,
        @UID,@TCPIP,'COMPLETION INSERT')

    SELECT @changelogid = Scope_identity()

    EXEC Auditrecordaction
        @emp,
        @date,
        @payfrequency,
        @c_insertaction,
        @actiondate,
        @UID,
        @actionid OUT,
        @doaudit OUT

    SELECT @doaudit DoAudit, @actionid ActionID

    IF Isnull(@doaudit, 0) > 0
    BEGIN 

        IF @mode = @c_current
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO timedetail_audit (
                EMPNUM,PPENDDATE,TSDATE,TASK1,
                TASK2,TASK3,HOURS,MINUTES,
                DOECODE,DURATION,SOURCE,TSGROUP,
                DEPTCHRG,PAYRATE,TIMEIN,TIMEOUT,
                ERRORS,COMPLETED,APPROVED,VERIFIED,
                DELETED,PROCESSEDBYPAYROLL,ID,ENTEREDBY,
                ENTEREDON,APPROVEDBY,APPROVEDON,PROCESSEDON,
                QUANTITY,SHIFT,processed_pd,RUNNUMBER,
                overnight,actionid,logid)
            SELECT
                EMPNUM,PPENDDATE,TSDATE,TASK1,
                TASK2,TASK3,HOURS,MINUTES,
                DOECODE,DURATION,SOURCE,TSGROUP,
                DEPTCHRG,PAYRATE,TIMEIN,TIMEOUT,
                ERRORS,COMPLETED,APPROVED,VERIFIED,
                DELETED,PROCESSEDBYPAYROLL,ID,ENTEREDBY,
                ENTEREDON,APPROVEDBY,APPROVEDON,PROCESSEDON,
                QUANTITY,SHIFT,processed_pd,RUNNUMBER,
                overnight,@actionid,@changelogid
            FROM timedetail
            WHERE empnum = @EMP
                AND tsdate = @DATE
                AND id = @nextid

        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO timedetail_audit (
                EMPNUM,PPENDDATE,TSDATE,TASK1,
                TASK2,TASK3,HOURS,MINUTES,
                DOECODE,DURATION,SOURCE,TSGROUP,
                DEPTCHRG,PAYRATE,TIMEIN,TIMEOUT,
                ERRORS,COMPLETED,APPROVED,VERIFIED,
                DELETED,PROCESSEDBYPAYROLL,ID,ENTEREDBY,
                ENTEREDON,APPROVEDBY,APPROVEDON,PROCESSEDON,
                QUANTITY,SHIFT,processed_pd,RUNNUMBER,
                overnight,actionid,logid)
            SELECT
                EMPNUM,PPENDDATE,TSDATE,TASK1,
                TASK2,TASK3,HOURS,MINUTES,
                DOECODE,DURATION,SOURCE,TSGROUP,
                DEPTCHRG,PAYRATE,TIMEIN,TIMEOUT,
                ERRORS,COMPLETED,APPROVED,VERIFIED,
                DELETED,PROCESSEDBYPAYROLL,ID,ENTEREDBY,
                ENTEREDON,APPROVEDBY,APPROVEDON,PROCESSEDON,
                QUANTITY,SHIFT,processed_pd,RUNNUMBER,
                overnight,@actionid,@changelogid
            FROM adjst_timedetail
            WHERE empnum = @EMP
                AND tsdate = @DATE
                AND id = @nextid

        END
    END 
END
```

Comment: No error messages in the query output?  How are you running the query?  The query can't arbitrarily bomb out in the middle of a statement without at least a message explaining why.

Comment: If you delete out the if block above does it execute?

Comment: Could you please post entire procedure? This does not look complete.

Answer (score 0):

If this piece executes without errors....

```
IF @mode = @c_current
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO timedetail (
        ppenddate,tsdate,empnum,task1,
        task2,task3,hours,minutes,
        doecode,duration,SOURCE,enteredby,
        enteredon,approved,completed,timein,
        timeout,id)
    VALUES(
        @DATE,@DATE,@EMP,' ',
        ' ',' ',0,0,
        ' ',0,'BROWSER',@UID,
        @actiondate,'N','Y',' ',
        ' ',@nextid)

END
ELSE
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO adjst_timedetail (
        ppenddate,tsdate,empnum,task1,
        task2,task3,hours,minutes,
        doecode,duration,SOURCE,enteredby,
        enteredon,approved,completed,timein,
        timeout,id)
    VALUES (
        @DATE,@DATE,@EMP,' ',
        ' ',' ',0,0,
        ' ',0,'BROWSER',@UID,
        @actiondate,'N','Y',' ',
        ' ',@nextid)

END
```

then the next statement should and will try to execute. My guess is you're missing some errors here. Try running it from management studio in chunk to make sure they are in fact executing successfully.

Comment: It doesn't error it just doesn't run that block of code where indicated